# How to use accented characters in /etc/fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I would like to mount an SMB share, so I added an entry in **/etc/fstab**:

```
//192.168.2.200/rendetlenseg /media/Rendetlenség cifs credentials=/home/<user>/.smbcredentials,uid=<user>,gid=<user>,user,bind  0 0
```

The mount point called "**Rendetlenség**".

When mount point is `/media/Rendetlenseg`, it works perfectly, however when it's `/media/Rendetlenség` (accented character: "é"), I get an error message:

[image]

So I created a new subfolder in /media : `Rendetlens\303\251g` but it couldn't solve this problem: there is still no such file or directory.

Comment: Octal representation is known to work for single-byte characters like space (`\040`) - I've never tried it for multibyte characters but it might be worth a try (é is `\303\251` I think)

Comment: ... or possibly URI encoded as `%E9`